# Integration of function/derivative

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I've been trying to find a function from a functional equation by the Newton-Leibnitz theorem and I'm getting two integrands, one of the form $~\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}~$ [which will yield $~\ln f(x)~$] and the other of the form $~\dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}~$ which I am unable to integrate.

Can somebody give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: For first substitute t by f(x) we get $\ln {|f(x)|}$

Comment: Yeah, I know the first one. Can't seem to get a hold on the second one.

Comment: See [$\displaystyle\int\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3673816/721644)