# Is there a general solution to the integral $\int \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}dx$?

Tags: integration

I am trying to find a general solution in terms of $x$ and $f(x)$ of the integral

$$ \int \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}dx$$

I tried partial integration, substitution and tried using the fact that $\frac{1}{f'(x)}$ is equal to $(f^{-1})'(y)$.

If the general integral does not exist, which criteria for $f$ do we have to add to make it solvable?

**Edit:** As Robert Israel pointed out, a "general solution" as described above does not exist. The question, for what $f$ one can formulate a closed-form solution, remains.

For instance, let us suppose that $f$ is a polynomial. Do we then get a closed-form solution?

Comment: We know the antiderivative of any rational function, whether it's of the form $f(x)/f'(x)$ or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is certainly no simple expression for this in terms of $x$ and $f(x)$.

$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} F(x, f(x)) = F_1(x, f(x)) + f'(x) F_2(x, f(x))$$
where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the partial derivatives of $F$.  No way to get $f'$ in the denominator.

Of course, in particular cases you may be able to get closed-form expressions.

Comment: That is a nice explanation! Thank you! Even though it leads to the  unsatisfactory result that I expected :/... do you know in what cases for $f$ I get a closed-form solution?